# How to use Analogue Sticks (joystick) output values to rotate an object using transform matrix?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

Given that analog stick outputs values

```
float xaxisval = controller->left_stick_x_axis(); //-1 is left, 1 is right
float yaxisval = controller->left_stick_y_axis(); //-1 is up, 1 is down
```

Values go from 0 to 1 with which can be used for sensitivity.

I'm moving the character in the direction of the joystick in a 3D environment the same way you would in a game like Diablo. I'm adding and retracting these values from X and Z position to move him. But the character is always facing the same dierection. 
How can I use these values and convert them into degrees?

```
xaxisval += controller->left_stick_x_axis() /100;
yaxisval += controller->left_stick_y_axis() /100;
distAdjust.SetTranslation(Vector4(xaxisval, 0, yaxisval));

rotateAdjust.RotationX(rotateDegrees);

player_->set_transform(player_transform *distAdjust *rotateAdjust)
```

Problem I have is the movement only works with fixed rotation, if I rotate the object then it moves into a different direction.

Comment: Are you trying to calculate an angle from your x/y axis values? If so, then `atan2` from `<math.h>` can do that. Check out the example at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/atan2/

Comment: Please be more specific about what kind of movement you want. I assume this is 2D?

Comment: @Nico No, this is a lovked perspective game, 3D environment where I want to move the player character around like you would in diablo. Using just the joystick.

Comment: So, that would mean - the horizontal axis of the joystick makes your character rotate around its vertical axis and the vertical axis of the joystick makes your player move forward/backward?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your function "rotateAdjust.RotationX(rotateDegrees);" really do.

But, you should for every game cycle take the value from 0 to 1 from your joystick, then multiply it by a constant angle depending of your rotation speed.

```
const float Angle = 1.0f; // Or whatever you want. Set more to increase rotation speed.

...

// Game loop
while ( true )
{
  ...

  float xSensitivity = controller->left_stick_x_axis(); // example 0.33f for that cycle

  myGuy.xRotate(Angle * xSensitivity);

  ...
}
```

"Angle" is a constant and can be expressed in degree or radian depending of your rotation function.